# Xamarin Forms using an anonymous method within a For loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, xamarin.forms, anonymous-function

In the below For loop, after the loop has finished, it increments the counter one last time e.g. if the condition is i<2, it will increment to 2 before exiting the loop. The images list will then try to use the value images[2] which doesn't exist. This will result in images not displaying

I know there are other questions on using an anonymous method within a loop and I've applied the recommended solutions, but no such luck.

This is my code behind

```
FileModel fileModel = DependencyService.Get<IImageFetcher>().ReadImagesAsync();

    var items = new List<FileImageInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileModel.Images.Count; i++)
    {
        var imageStream = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(fileModel.Images[i]));
        items.Add(new FileImageInfo
        {
            FileType = "Jpeg",
            FileSize = fileModel.Sizes[i],
            DateCreated = fileModel.Dates[i],
            imageSource = imageStream
        });
    }
    Items.ItemsSource = items;
```

[image]

the above code works indicating the issue is definitely with the loop and not with the images or anything else

Comment: which specific line throws the exception, and what is the specific exception?  It's unlikely the for loop itself is the problem - you could change it to a foreach to check.  Are you sure that Images, Sizes, and Dates are always the same length?  Finally, this is basic C#, it has nothing specific to do with Xamarin

Comment: Where is this anonymous method you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach loop did the trick. Was told over on the Xamarin forum that have to use foreach not For with listview images